# How to send a get request then parse it to get the token and again use the same session to send a post request with that token to website in C#?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient, httpwebresponse

I need to send a get request (sessions) to a website that contains a hidden token as `"__RequestVerificationToken"`. Afterthat, I want to parse the token and again send the post request with UserName, Password and also this parsed hiddenToken.

I know how to do it in python, this is the following code to implement in python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
session = requests.session() # Session Created
url ="some URL"
initial_login = session.get(url) # sending a get request to parse the token
soup = BeautifulSoup(initial_login.text,'html.parser')
token=soup.find('input') # used BeautifulSoup to find token
payload = { 'Username':'username','Password':'password','__RequestVerificationToken':token['value']}
login_done = session.post(url,data=payload)
login_cookie= login_done.cookies['APILogin']
```

Please tell me how to achieve the same in C#...

Comment: Look into [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) or [HTMLAgilityParser](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack) then create a question when you are stuck.

Comment: @aloisdg I used HTMLAgilityParser and i was able to parse the token, the problem i faced is how to use the same request object to send a post request by sending that token. If i create a new request object to send post request then that token is not valid.